# How can I add a dependency after I have created a package?

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I created a package called demo. It has two dependencies

1. roscpp
2. robot_comm

Now I want to interface it with a sensor, so I created a node called 'cell_node' for the sensor. I plan to use information from a topic in 'cell_node' which publishes the message 'loadMsg' at 50Hz.

But then, I am getting an error

cell_node/loadMsg.h : No such file or directory.

I kind of know why this is happening. It is because I never added cell_node to the list of dependencies when I first created my package demo.

My question is, **how can I add a new dependency to an already existing package, so that it compiles code in that dependency too?**

Thanks! All help is appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38299/how-can-i-add-a-dependency-after-i-have-created-a-package?/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-07-09**:
Thanks Rydel! I found the answer here

http://answers.ros.org/question/9177/adding-a-dependency-after-roscreate-pkg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in the manifest.xml file of your package add a dependency near the others

```
<depend package="cell_node"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) with karma: 600 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4